# Do we need a hardware tag?

Tags: discussion

[hardware](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) tag is useless on a site focused on hardware. I vote to burninate this tag.

Answer (score 4):

Currently (as of 2021-07-18) there are 393 questions tagged [hardware](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and 23 tag watchers. 28 of the questions have been "favorite" bookmarked and there are a lot of upvoted questions and answers, so there is some quality content here that we should try to preserve.

However it does seem like anything that isn't "hardware" doesn't really belong here, so the tag itself seems redundant. In many cases, the questions and answers would still be useful and could be found without the "hardware" tag, but there are a few questions that would be left untagged.

I ran a SE data query to find questions that have no other tags besides "hardware" (link below); so before we delete the tag [hardware](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware), we should examine each of these (29) remaining questions and either retag or close/delete these questions, otherwise they will become untagged. Some of these questions have accepted answers, multiple answers, upvotes, bookmarks (favorite), so there's some value worth saving.

We should try to retag only a few at a time, to avoid spamming the "active questions" page -- retagging a question bumps it up to the front of the list, and it doesn't take very much retagging activity to drown out actual new questions.

As of 2021-07-17, these are the questions that have only the single tag [hardware](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware):

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [KiCAD - Errors when designing shield schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/533125) | 2020-11-19 00:45:12 |  |
| [Confused about the meaning of hardware specification](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/531076) | 2020-11-07 00:01:39 |  |
| [Logic to pull signal low on power loss until signals next rising edge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/524010) | 2020-09-30 16:01:55 |  |
| [How to adjust trim potentiometer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/508794) | 2020-07-03 23:15:48 |  |
| [Step up 5V to a range of 7V - 12V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/417106) | 2019-01-15 14:06:44 | 2019-01-20 23:55:13 |
| [What happens when Schottky diode is protecting a pin from overvoltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/374530) | 2018-05-16 03:38:45 |  |
| [Why are hardware inverters so prevalent?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/369688) | 2018-04-20 14:54:10 |  |
| [AVR with a lot of outputs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/348031) | 2018-01-04 02:06:52 | 2018-01-04 18:00:04 |
| [Understanding a Hardware Description Language, circa 1965](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/332518) | 2017-10-03 03:28:05 |  |
| [Yamaha DTX Multi-12 drum pad SW/HW hack](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/330589) | 2017-09-22 00:01:18 | 2017-09-22 22:58:47 |
| [Schematic on LT Spice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/325597) | 2017-08-24 11:36:42 |  |
| [How to deduce number of possible states for an adder](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/303987) | 2017-05-07 19:28:47 |  |
| [Exactly how much programming will I be doing if I work as a hardware design engineer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/239502) | 2016-06-06 18:20:27 | 2016-06-06 19:12:46 |
| [What type of screw driver do I need for this type of small socket 5 sided star screw?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/226201) | 2016-04-03 17:24:08 | 2016-04-04 00:05:59 |
| [XMC module in electronics industry](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/188858) | 2015-09-03 19:20:27 |  |
| [Sound Box - Custom Message](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/173407) | 2015-06-01 14:43:06 |  |
| [how to convert 1.5v 150ma to 5v 2 amp?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/159058) | 2015-03-10 06:11:26 | 2016-08-09 02:12:24 |
| [Power multiple 5V/12V devices off a single transformer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/153946) | 2015-02-12 17:00:44 | 2015-02-13 11:03:59 |
| [Executing push $reg using one instruction on single cycle datapath](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/139307) | 2014-11-20 07:01:08 |  |
| [What would I call this specific type of knob?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/137950) | 2014-11-10 18:14:41 |  |
| [Given hardware specs: How do I calculate the data bandwidth [bits/s] of this system?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/136580) | 2014-10-31 03:33:35 |  |
| [Why isn't homemade hardware a thing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/123482) | 2014-07-31 00:04:59 | 2014-07-31 01:29:28 |
| [Easiest way to display 10 colours in a small area](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93653) | 2013-12-14 03:35:34 |  |
| [The effect of the increase in the number of transistors in a chip on a processor's peformance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/92818) | 2013-12-05 23:43:48 |  |
| [Can electrical contacts 'burn out'?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/86941) | 2013-10-30 08:57:34 |  |
| [Is it safe to clean out a computer with air compressor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/79613) | 2013-08-20 21:20:56 | 2013-08-21 13:39:24 |
| [Hardware block to determine if a number is a multiple of 8](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/74923) | 2013-07-04 16:26:18 |  |
| [How to design a hardware standard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/74609) | 2013-07-01 14:47:00 | 2013-07-01 18:07:29 |
| [Which are hardware projects management guidelines in your organization](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/9266) | 2011-01-21 13:34:15 |  |

For reference, the query is here (originally from user Passerby):

https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/372728/find-questions-with-a-single-tag-now-case-insensitive?Tag=hardware

```
Declare @Tags nvarchar(150)
Set @Tags='<##Tag##>'
Set @Tags = Lower(@Tags)

Select Top 5000 Id As [Post Link], CreationDate, ClosedDate
From Posts
Where Title is not null And Tags=@Tags
Order By CreationDate Desc
```

When there are no longer any questions meeting this criteria, it will then be safe to delete the tag administratively, and blacklist it (I think that requires one of the diamond-moderators).